# Use ffmpeg to encode folder of yuyv frames into an mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, raw

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to generate an mp4 file from a few thousand frames I have in yuyv format (yuyv422 in ffmpeg terms).  I've found some command lines to join a bunch of images like this, but how do I do it with a directory of raw frames?  I'd also like to specify the bitrate and framerate if that's possible too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic command template is

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -c:v rawvideo -framerate 24 -video_size 1920x1080 -pixel_format yuyv422
       -i path/to/img%d.raw -b:v 2000k output.mp4
```

Comment: The `-b:v` option is not necessary (*ffmpeg 4.1.3*). I'm getting the exact same video (same checksum) with or without the option

Comment: Can't reproduce it here. Share full log of your two runs - with and without b:v.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tFag1gfR - It seems the encoder simply ignore the bitrate (which makes sense since we're encoding raw). It also seems to ignore the framerate in my case (*edit* the only difference with / without the -b:v option is the speedup)

Comment: `b:v` is *bit*rate, so the `1000` in your command is 1 kbps which ffmpeg will ignore and override with default rate. You're also assigning 'rawvideo' as the output encoder (my command does not), where bitrate does not matter.